# RLE algorithm C

Tags: c, algorithm, compression

here is the RLE algorithm on C, but it is doesn't work!

![][1]

where is the problem?
original and encoded strings are not displaying
help me please
why the result is not displayed?
I need to finish it soon, so I hope you can help ti make it work.
thank you for attention

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include< stdio.h>
#include< conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include< string.h>
void main()
{
    int i, j, cnt, l, count[50] = { 0 };
    char str[50];
    system("cls");
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf_s("%s", str);
    printf("\n\tOriginal String is: %s", str);
    printf("\n\n\tEncoded String is: ");
    l = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i< l; i *= 1)
    {
        j = 0;
        count[i] = 1;
        do
        {
            j++;
            if (str[i + j] == str[i])
                count[i]++;
        } while (str[i + j] == str[i]);
        if (count[i] == 1)
            printf("%c", str[i++]);
        else
        {
            printf("%d%c", count[i], str[i]);
            i += count[i];
        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: You may want to [flush the output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Comment: should be `scanf_s("%s", str, 50);`

Answer (score 1):

Biggest problem: You have

```
for (i = 0; i< l; i *= 1)
//                  ^ multiplication
```

anything multplied by `1` does not change value; this is an infinite loop

Comment: There is no need for it have been performed increment elsewhere, but the `i *= 1` is not a bug.

Comment: Hmmm ... on 2nd reading I see `i` being changed inside the loop. I suggest replacing the `for` with `while (i < l)`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem can be trying to access array element out of bound:

See, suppose i=45 and initially j will be 1
     if all characters till index 49 are same as index 45, then j will be 5 and you will access str[i+j] i.e. str[45+5]=str[50] which is undefined, because your array limit is 50.
So what i think is you should also check the index is within bound.

```
    do
    {
        j++;
        if ((i+j)<50 && (str[i + j] == str[i]))
            count[i]++;
    } while ((i+j)<50 && (str[i + j] == str[i]));
```